# Has anyone been able to get this require or debug NPM module to work in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, npm, console.log

Has anyone been able to get this [require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require) or [debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) NPM module to work in the browser?

According to the screenshots & instructions on the [debug NPM module's](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug#browser-support) page, it's possible to use it that way. However, attempting to use it causes this error to appear:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

How do I solve this problem? I know that the [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) NPM module allows us to use the `require()` method & it requires transpiling from ES6 -> ES5. So I've tried getting around that transpiling requirement by installing the [require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require) NPM module... but that doesn't work either.

Question is: Has anyone been able to get either the require or debug modules to work in browser? If so, how did you make them work?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.

*helloworld.js*:

```
// create a logger with name `hello-world`
const debug = require('debug')('hello-world');
debug('hello world');
```

*index.html*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      // enable loggers with name matching `hello-world`
      localStorage.debug = 'hello-world'
    </script>
    <script src='bundle.js'></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

To generate `bundle.js`, you can use Browserify:

```
$ browserify helloworld.js > bundle.js
```